# Designing an upload service. Helper/Utility class in OOP

Tags: c#, oop, sharepoint, file-upload

I've recently graduated from college, joined an established software company and was attached to a team size of 18.

I was tasked to write a code that uploads generated report (Report A) up onto a file dump area such as SharePoint. Our app now generates many reports (Report A to Z). But i was tasked only to do for Report A right now.

Almost effortlessly, i knew i had to design my upload service that allow Report (B to Z) to use my service easily in the future without much trouble.

A veteran in the team, told me to do up a single helper/utility class that uploads the file.

However, the design I came up with involves factory design pattern that returns a Report A Uploader which inherits from an Uploader abstract class and it calls  an UploadService file.
In future, Report B to Z can just simply inherit from Uploader abstract class and implement a method that determines the destination to be uploaded.

So I am confused, did i really over-thinked this problem? Was i wrong in my design?

Comment: simple answer: you are not wrong in your design. complex answer: do whatever you team lead demands you to do. and ask him directly what you want and then try to think.  Having complex thinking sometimes not required.

Answer (score 0):

It's not really possible to say whether the design is "wrong" or "right" without knowing all of the criteria that would make it correct. In general, the team lead *should* know more than juniors about those criteria (but not always). Also remember that there is a difference between "right" and "optimum".

Experienced developers in a commercial environment often trade off "good" design against "quick" solutions, and often this trade off is done implicitly. They also learn to distrust complexity. Often the team lead will be doing this when they say "do X".

The best team leads will explain their thought process to less experienced members to help them understand how the trade offs are made, and make them better developers.

It would be a good idea to check with the lead if you think your design is too complex. Rather than say "How do I...", say something like "I think we should ... because...". Good managers love it when their team members show initiative and will be even more motivated to share what they know.